# Prevent image width shrinking on nextjs tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am working on a website and it looks fine on my screen.

[image]

However, the image div is shrinking on a smaller screen or on a mobile while the text is alright.

[image]

How do I fix it so users are able to see the image regardless of screen size?

```html
<div className="flex justify-center items-center p-5" id="intro">
  <div className="relative w-[500px] h-[500px]">
    <Image src="/blank.png" alt="blank face" fill={true} />
  </div>
  <div className="flex-col justify-center align-middle items-center p-5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying `flex-shrink: 0` to the `<div>` wrapping the `<Image>` component via the `shrink-0` utility class so that it does not shrink:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flex justify-center items-center p-5" id="intro">
  <div class="relative w-[500px] h-[500px] shrink-0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="blank face" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; object-fit: cover; color: transparent;" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col justify-center align-middle items-center p-5">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae justo placerat, consequat nulla quis, mollis elit. Aenean ultrices risus in tellus mollis luctus. Nullam tortor nisi, tincidunt eget lorem sit amet, porttitor ullamcorper nisi. Curabitur a erat vitae elit dignissim pellentesque et sit amet purus. Curabitur nec augue blandit, tincidunt odio iaculis, pretium erat. Donec id sapien ut purus auctor dapibus. Quisque luctus non sapien id ultricies. Quisque cursus velit sollicitudin neque ullamcorper, quis accumsan felis scelerisque. Ut volutpat quis purus nec bibendum.
  </div>
</div>
```